# Tap background to dismiss TextField keyboard only if keyboard is active

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I keep having an issue with a textfield I have set as a decimal keyboard, because its the decimal keyboard it doesn't have a return key so I have to tap background to dismiss it. I want to only allow it to recognize that tap if the keyboard is open. Currently it recognizes it anytime you tap the background. Any help would be awesome thanks.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    label.text = "tapped"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this extension, it worked for me:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Then put this `self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()` in `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```